# Send parameter to function from function pointer C++

Tags: c++

I wondered if you can send an function pointer to function and form the second function (that got the function pointer ) to call the function in the parameter with a parameter
I mean :

```
main.cpp:
 *obj << foo; \\ while foo gets *obj as parameter
obj.h:
class obj
{
...
obj& operator<<(void(*pf)());
obj& operator<<(void(*pf)(obj));
};
foo(*obj x)
```

Comment: you want to call the function that is passed to `operator<<` ?

Comment: It's a bit unclear what you are asking.  Yes, you can overload a function on the type of a function pointer parameter.  Though your example is broken since the overload expects an `obj`, but `foo` takes a `*obj`.

Comment: wait what .....

Comment: did you try something and got compiler errors? If so, please show that code and the compiler errors. Apart from minor typos your code looks ok-ish, and it is not completely clear what you are asking

Comment: I want to get at first function pointer then to call the function with parm

Comment: ok, thats already something. Now, what is the problem? You want to call the function and pass the parameter, what prevents you from doing it? what did you try? how did it fail?

Comment: because foo get prarm I cant send it via <<

Comment: I want to sent pointer of function the get parms without to sending the parms

Comment: You may want to create a [mcve] to illustrate your question (with emphasis on the example being self-contained).

Comment: It sounds like what you're trying to do is similar to how manipulators (like `std::setw`) work with streams.

Comment: can I convert void* to function pointer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is possible. Using a function pointer you can call the function it points to. It doesn't matter if that function pointer is passed to another function or in a class or somewhere else.

Here is a short example.

As you can see I have `foo` which is a function pointer to the `function1` and passing it to `function2` which receives a function pointer and a number. Inside main I'm calling `function2` passing it `foo` and the value `5`. `function2`  will then call the function pointed by the `some_function` parameter which we know is `function1`. In other words `function2` is calling `function1` with the value of `5`.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void function1(int num)
{
    cout << "Your number is: " << num;
}

void function2( void (*some_function)(int) , int number )
{
    some_function(number);
}

int main()
{
  void (*foo)(int);
  foo = &function1;
  function2(foo,5);
}

//Output
//Your number is: 5
```

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: ok but is it somewhat related to your question ? Can you explain further from here or is this answer completely irrelevant ?